# Using a LiPo battery or different battery for outside project

Tags: batteries, solar-energy

First I am sorry if this is the wrong section to post this, I have been searching for a clear answer and haven't found one yet.

I have a project that I want to keep outside. I have a solar panel, charging circuit and a Lipo battery. It works great, though I have read a lot about how LiPo batteries can fail and catch fire.

I am wondering if Lipo is the way to go for something that will stay outside for years. It could get cold and hot from the sun :/

Should I redesign to use a lead acid? Would it be safer???

I know that was a lot, If this is the wrong place for this please let me know and I can remove this post,

If this is the right place, thank you so much for the assistance.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LiPo / LiIon batteries are almost always safe when charged and discharged within specs.

To get usefully longer lifetimes

- Try to charge to less than the usual 4.2V (say 4.1 or even 4.0 V)
  This gives longer and much longer cycle lives and whole of life capacity at cost of some per cycle capacity.
- Do not discharge under say 3.2V.
- Terminate CV phase of charging at *high* current - say CC/2.
- Be sure CCCV charging is done correctly and NEVER "float" at 4.2V once charging is complete.

With solar you may have variable rate charging. This is acceptable as long as CC rate is within spec. Some cells allow C/1 and some C/2 rates. C/2 is less stressful.

LiFePO4 is better again for longevity and safety.

Look at manufacturer's temperature limits and observe them.
How cold does it get. Sub zero temperatures can cause issues if specs not met.

Ventilate to ensure summer temperatures are as low as reasonable.

How long is "years"?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, By "Years" I mean a maximum of 2-3 years before I plan to replace the unit. And as an fyi, i am using this: https://www.adafruit.com/product/390 as my charging unit.
I also would love to ask, Can a LiFePO4 battery be charged using a LiPo charger like that one I have? or would I need to find something totally different?

Comment: That charger works only with LiIon or LiPo. || LiFePO$ needs aabout 3.65V cjarge termination voltage. Some chargers can be adjusted to suit. If it doesn't say so in the spec it is almost certain that it is not capable of liFePO4 charging.

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is a somewhat sealed project, if you have room for a lead acid then have a look into LiFe batteries, they are similar to LiPo, but without most of the safety concerns of LiPo

Lead acid will have some small off gassing, and the hydrogen can cause solder joints to become brittle, this is part of my reason for steering away from that, if you have some mitigation towards that then lead acid should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend you to use dry batteries, a bit more expensive then lead acid batteries but its good for projects that have a low discharge rate like a UPS and not recommended for cars and stuff. You also have to be careful not to over or undercharge it, but i think a proper circuit will solve that. But, on the bright side there are no gases that can damage the solder joint. I think you ought to a research a bit before using it to see if it suits your application

Comment: For most projects, if the OP has chosen rechargeable batteries, the chances of dry cells being adequiate are usually small. Sometimes they do suit.

Comment: yes, that's true. They only suit few applications but when they do then they work like a charm.